# What happens when I join a domain in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, domain

I am thinking about joining our company domain with a linux box.
With joining the domain I can use single sign on for a web service we are running ([Dekiwiki](http://www.mindtouch.com)), for this I have installed winbind. And I am thinking about the limitations that might come after we joined the domain like internet access, user management on the local computer and others.

Ton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux, Samba is just another server daemon (or service client, if you're not running the server portion).  Neither server nor client can automagically take over the administration of the Linux box just because you've told them to join a Windows Domain.

Now, if you *wanted* to force all local users to login and authenticate to the WDS, you can.  (I think.)  But that's not a requirement.  Without special configuration, it won't affect your linux box's standard networking and user management.

Here's the [Samba HOWTO on Domain Membership](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/domain-member.html) for joining with a Samba server, or see [this subsection](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/domain-member.html#domain-member-server) if you're joining via the Samba client (ie not running a Samba server on the box).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification that joining the domain won't affect current user management.

Answer (score 3):

Using nss_winbind or nss_ldap with PAM (pam_krb5, and/or pam_winbind/pam_ldap, you can have the domain users show up on the linux box and enjoy single sign on capabilities of the domain.